# How to get last month date from selected date in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

selected date is (txtfromdate) : Dec 01 2016

to date:(txttodate): Dec 31 2016

how to calculate Dec 31 2016 from Dec 01 2016 in c# or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime firstOfDecember = new DateTime(2016, 12, 1);
int lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(firstOfDecember.Year, firstOfDecember.Month);
```

If you want to create DateTime object equivalent to last day of the month:

```
DateTime lastOfDecember = new DateTime(firstOfDecember.Year, firstOfDecember.Month, lastDay);
```

Use `DaysInMonth` method of `DateTime`: [**DateTime.DaysInMonth Method (Int32, Int32)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use DaysInMonth

```
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime (year, month,DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using JQuery

```
var selectedData = txtfromdate;
var date = new Date(selectedData);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

So, In lastDay variable has result.

By Using C#

```
DateTime now = new Date(txtfromdate);
var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

In endDate variable has lastDate.